# How to automatically detect outdoor webcams from webpages?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, webcam, webcam.js

I'm interested in automatically identifying webcams/livecams in websites. Are there any common, identifiers in a website-based webcam/livecam that I could use? My ultimate goal is to programmatically scan a website and yield a url to the webcam/livecam.

A simple website search such as "webcam" or "live cam" would work to initially bring the focus to the website of interest, however, it would not yield a url to the webcam output.

For example, here are some examples of web cams that I am looking to automatically identify:

- https://hdontap.com/index.php/video
- http://www.earthcam.com/mapsearch/

Comment: The answer is probably *probably not*. At least for anything close to 100% success rate.

Comment: @deceze Even a 60% success rate would be sufficient.

Comment: Well, look for Flash or HTML 5 `<video>` elements. If those are being embedded through Javascript instead of being in the plain HTML, that becomes pretty tricky though…